# How can I install our iPhone project without connect the device but only using device ID?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to build my iPhone app only using device ID without connecting the device to my apple PC. Can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clearify it a bit for us? Is like the answers below suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simulator, and never develop on the device. Is that what you mean? I wouldn't like to be one of your customers when I bought that app from the appstore in that case though - there would be so many defects.

If you don't mean that, how would you get the app on your device? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Are you suggesting that you do not want to test your app on a real device before releasing it? Please don't do that. There are a lot of differences when testing the app on a device or on simulator.

If you want to create a build for adhoc testing without connecting a device to your mac, you can do that by simply creating a mobileprovision file for adhoc testing where you can specify upto 100 device ids. For this you need to be a member of the Apple Developer Program though.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question right, you want to put your app on your phone without actually connecting your phone?

If so, it is not possible.  You must connect your phone to load applications you develop.

Answer (score 0):

if you are registered iPhone developer, u can create Ad Hoc distribution via defining device ids that you want the app to be used (steps are listed at 'Program Portal User Guide' at apple's developer site). then u can install the app on your device via iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't install just based on the device number or something else. 
There are two solutions:
1/But what you can do without plugging the phone is to Post your App on some testing platform like TestFlight, or Answers. And you enter users' email address and they can get the email.
2/You can set up a config file that declare your OS X Server address. And add the iPhone into your Server Open Directory. Then you can send and deploy the app to iPhone devices.
If you have future questions, comment.